# Check browser width after resize, without reload (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a small piece of Javascript that checks what the browser's width is on load and, depending on the result, runs a piece of jQuery. This to display a different menu on mobile devices

However, it CAN happen a user starts with a very small browser on his desktop, running the jQuery (and therefore the mobile menu). If he then resizes to full-screen, the menu doesn't change, because the check on the browser's width doesn't run again.

The question: How do I adapt the Javascript so it checks every time the browser is resized?

My code:

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 992) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".main-menu").hide();
        $(".mobile-nav-button").click(function() {
            $(".main-menu").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
}
else {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".mobile-nav-button").hide();
        $(".mobile-cart-button").hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a resize function wrapper like this:

```
function resize(){
    // do all your stuff here
}
```

And then call it once on page load, and recall it on every resize event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resize();
    $(window).resize(resize);
});
```

Instead of the wrapper you could also use an anonymous function (`$(window).resize(function(){/*Do stuff here*/})`), but then you can't call your function on page load and you'd have to repeat yourself.

### Your specific case

In your specific case you'd have to take out the document readys. Heres how it should look:

```
function resize(){
    // First we need to show all, then we will selectively hide based on page width
    $(".main-menu, .mobile-nav-button, .mobile-cart-button").show();
    if (window.innerWidth <= 992) {
        $(".main-menu").hide();
        // also, because you bind a click event here, you'll need to unbind it every time
        // otherwise it will be executed multiple times after a couple of resizes
        // (you could also do what @david does and move this into the document.ready below)
        $(".mobile-nav-button").off("click").click(function() {
            // slideToggle will toggle display of an element, but because its wrapped in click()
            // it only gets executed onclick, not resize. Also, you don't want animation on resize.
            $(".main-menu").slideToggle(500);
        });
    } else {
        $(".mobile-nav-button").hide();
        $(".mobile-cart-button").hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    resize();
    $(window).resize(resize);
});
```

### A snippet

Below is a snippet with the code working. I reduced the width to 700 pixels so I could see the effects at a smaller screen difference (because that how the snippet editor looks) but it all works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mobile-nav-button">Mobile Nav Button</div>
    <div class="mobile-cart-button">Mobile CART Button</div>
    <div class="main-menu">MAIN MENU</dov>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resize(){
            $(".mobile-nav-button, .mobile-cart-button, .main-menu").show();
            if (window.innerWidth <= 700) {
                $(".main-menu").hide();
                $(".mobile-nav-button").off("click").click(function() {
                    $(".main-menu").slideToggle(500);
                });
            } else {
                $(".mobile-nav-button").hide();
                $(".mobile-cart-button").hide();
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            resize();
            $(window).resize(resize);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, I copied the "your case" code, but it doesn't work at all. Neither does the other answer. What am I doing wrong here? It sounds like it should just work. Edit: The buttons (mobile-nav-button etc.) don't get hidden and the toggle-able menu is just always active when I get below 992 pixels.

Comment: The problem Im seeing is that you are hiding, but not showing. Let me amend my code a bit :)

Comment: Hmm, but shouldn't `slideToggle` do that? I'm pretty new to this, so I might've misunderstood.

Comment: `slidetoggle()` only gets executed on click, not on resize. And you are using `hide()` to hide all the elements, but not `show()` to display them. Forget the `slidetoggle`, that one is only `onclick`. So first `show()` everything, then hide what you shouldn't see on the page size. I have tested this locally (with element just containing the class name) and it works.

Comment: It's so weird. When working with my original code, it works perfectly fine (without the resizing of course), but as soon as I add something so it get's triggered when resized, it seems to completely ignore it. And I don't even `.show` everything first :S

Comment: Your snippet works beautifully. Will play around, maybe something else is cancelling the function. Will mark your answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Wanted to update why it didn't work with me: Apparently we have something installed that uses the `$` in its syntax, so I had to use `jq` instead. Adding the jQuery library overruled that custom rule, so that's why it worked. However, it would break other parts of the website. Well, that was fun! :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".mobile-nav-button").click(function() {
        $(".main-menu").slideToggle(500);
    });

    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 992) {
            $(".main-menu").hide();
        }
        else {

           $(".mobile-nav-button").hide();
           $(".mobile-cart-button").hide();

       }
    ));

    $(window).resize();


));
```

Comment: This will not execute on page load, though, you'd need to trigger it at least once for the changes to take effect.

Comment: oops forgot to add that in! :s thanks for the heads up ;) have updated my answer

Comment: When just plainly copying your code, it doesn't work. The menu is visible all the time (<992px) and clicking on the `.mobile-nav-button` doesn't do anything. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Just call resize function  on pageLoad

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).resize(YourFunctionName);
    $(window).resize();
 });

 function YourFunctionName() {
          // Here is your code which you want to run automatically on page resize.
  }
```

Comment: This will not execute on page load, though, you'd need to trigger it at least once for the changes to take effect.

Comment: hmm.. trigger may needed, as i havent tested it.